In solana anchor, how to use max_len macro to define multi-dimensional vector?
I'm using anchor to build solana program.
In account struct, I have multi-dimensional vector.
#[max_len(2,50)]
element: Vec<Vec<MyType>>,

In this case, what is the meaning of (2, 50)?
I want to element to be like this:
element = vec![vec![x,x,...50x], vec![x,x, ...50x]];

In this case, what is the right form of these two?
#[max_len(2,50)]
#[max_len(50,2)]

EDIT
#[max_len(50)]
element: [Vec<MyType>; 2]

In this case, each two vec can contain 50 elements?
Totally, element can contain 100 elements?

The documentation for max_len says:

For types that have a variable size like String and Vec, it is necessary to indicate the size by the max_len attribute. For nested types, it is necessary to specify a size for each variable type (see example).

Followed by:
    #[max_len(10, 5)]
    pub nested: Vec<Vec<u8>>,

Which goes Vec by Vec, so that would create enough space for 10 vecs with 5 u8s each.
Taken from https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.InitSpace.html
